# Showing a custom view when an arrow within an inputbox is pressed.(in react-native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new in react-native and i am trying to develop an app, where a want to find out at first, which type of user is connected (e.g. student, prof, ...). Based on that i can show ihm the possiblity he has to navigate on. I plan to do it exactly like the following image:
[Navigation help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHSRz.jpg)

Before the user can see, which possibilities he has to navigate on. He must give his status e.g. student, prof, ...).

If you dont completly understand, what i mean. You can find the demonstration here: https://www.hochschule-bochum.de/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You should add more details such as sample of your code and your execution log as it will help us help you. You can also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you understand how to properly ask a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker) to choose between `(Student, Professor etc.)`. Then based on that you can show the results